# InvalidArgumentException: Identifier "user.management.active" is not defined

Tags: php

I am trying to download qr of users into a PDF file but I am getting this error that user.management.active is not defined. I tried to track it down, but I can't pin point where the problem is.  Can someone please help me?

Error:
`[InvalidArgumentException: Identifier "user.management.active" is not defined. (uncaught exception) at /Library/WebServer/Documents/timekeeper_service/vendor/pimple/pimple/src/Pimple/Container.php line 96`

This is the code that I have now:

Provider

```
    public function register(Container $container)
{
    $container['user_management.active'] = $container->factory(function (Container $c) {
        /** @var Jade $jade */
        $jade = $c['jade_factory'];
        $jade->view = 'cms/user_management/active_users';

        /** @var UserManagementController $controller */
        $controller = new UserManagementController();
        $controller->setUserQuery(\UserQuery::create());
        $controller->setView($jade);

        return $controller;
    });
```

User Management

```
$user_management->get('/list/download_all_qr', 'user.management.active:qrToPdf');
```

Controller

```
public function qrToPdf(Application $app)
{
    $users = $this->user_query->find();
    $user_content = array();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $user_content[] = [
            'name'      => sprintf('%s, %s', $user->getLastName(), $user->getFirstName()),
            'qr_code'   => base64_encode(generateQrCode($user->getEmployeeId()))
        ];
    }

    /** @var Jade $jade */
    $jade = $app['jade_factory'];
    $jade->view = 'cms/user/download_all_qr';
    $jade->with(['users' => $user_content]);

    // Export to PDF
    $mpdf = new \mPDF();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($jade->render());
    $mpdf->Output('users_qr_'.Carbon::today()->toDateString().'.pdf', 'D');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have registered your factory as `user_management.active` but then you try to access to `user.management.active`

You have to change the dot after 'user' to underscore or the other way around.

```
$user_management->get('/list/download_all_qr', 'user_management.active:qrToPdf');
```